# Scala: How to do union of data frames in the loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to do union of data frame in the recursive method.

I am doing some calculations in the recursive method and filtering the data and storing in one variable. In 2nd iteration i will do some calculation and again i will store the data in same variable.when i am calling the method second time my first result is getting vanished.Ideally i have to store the result in one temp variable and i need to do union of all the result till the recursive method gets completed its execution.

Iteration1 output in df:

```
Col1   
    14      
    35
```

Iteration2 output in df:

```
Col1
    18      
    20
```

Now i need the final output as,

```
Col1
    14
    35
    18
    20
```

Code:

```
def myRecursiveMethod(first: List[List[String]],
                        Inputcolumnsdummy: List[List[String]],
                        secondInputcolumns: List[List[String]] = {

  val ongoingResult = doSomeCalculation(first,Inputcolumnsdummy, secondInputcolumns)
}
```

I want my code should be something like below,

```
def myRecursiveMethod(first: List[List[String]],
                        Inputcolumnsdummy: List[List[String]],
                        secondInputcolumns: List[List[String]]) = {

    val ongoingResult = doSomeCalculation(first, Inputcolumnsdummy, secondInputcolumns)
    Val temp = temp.union(ongoingResult)
}
```

Comment: why don't you use union or unionAll for merging two dataframes?

Comment: Where's the recursive call to `myRecursiveMethod`? Looks like you'd have to pass the result of `union` as the value of another argument you should add to the method.

Comment: @Ramesh Maharjan In order to do that we should have two data frames data available in my recursivemethod. When control goes to second iteration the first result is getting vanished and the second iteration data is storing in the variable.

Comment: why are you using recursive function for? There are already inbuilt functions for columnwise recursive manipulations and udf function for row-wise manipulation. why don't you try to get benefited from one of them or all of them? explain all the details in the question like why do you need recursive function and how you are accessing it. and we shall advise you better solution.

Comment: @Ramesh Maharjan Fine but i am already half way through so i would like to go further ahead with recursive method. Is there any limitation in recursivemethod to store the result in one temp and keep on unioning the data to that variable? Cant i do that?

Comment: Yes you can definitely do that .

Comment: @Ramesh Maharjan could you please help me how to achieve that..

Comment: for that you will have to provide me with how you are calling `myRecursiveMethod` and what is `doSomeCalculation` and `Inputcolumnsdummy` ? And how you are intending to use or using output from your recursive function? Can you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try: use `union` like this: `df1.union(df2)` or `df1.union(computation(df2,...))`.

Exemple below:

```
def doCompute(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val tmp: DataFrame = ... // TODO: call to your computation method
    tmp.show()
    df.union(tmp)
}

val df1: DataFrame = ...
val df2: DataFrame = ...
val df3: DataFrame = ...

var union_df: DataFrame = df1.union(doCompute(df2)).union(doCompute(df3))
```

One thing I did not understand in your question is how is your function `myRecursiveMethod` recursive? A recursive function calls itself, by definition. Not sure your question is really clear.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes from your example i am calling the doCompute method inside doCompute method definition based on some if condition untill the condition it is satisfied the method is executing. Only problem i am facing is i have to store the data from each iteration in one variable it should be global, it should hold the data till all the iterations gets completed. finally i would like to merge the data to show the output. tmp data i have to store in one variable and i need to union the result with next iteration result.

Comment: Can you rephrase your problem?